# Run adduser non-interactively

Tags: adduser

I'd like to use the `adduser` command to add a user (with disabled password) via a shell script.

By default, `adduser` prompts you for various values (e.g., Full Name). Is there any way to submit these values via command line? Or will I need to `useradd` instead?

Answer (score 411, accepted):

Use the `--gecos` option to skip the `chfn` interactive part.

```
adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" username
```

It's all in the man page. Not the most obvious formulation tho.

```
--gecos GECOS
          Set  the  gecos field for the new entry generated.  adduser will
          not ask for finger information if this option is given.
```

The GECOS field is a comma separated list as such: `Full name,Room number,Work phone,Home phone`, despite that man page mentions `finger information` [Details - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field)

Hope this helps you.

**Update:** for more recent (or upcoming) versions of `adduser`, the `--gecos` option is replaced by `--comment`.

```
--comment comment
      Set the comment field for the new entry generated.  adduser will
      not ask for the information if this option is given.  This field
      is  also  known under the name GECOS field and contains informa‐
      tion that is used by the finger command.  This used  to  be  the
      --gecos  option,  which  is deprecated and will be removed after
      Debian bookworm.  Valid Modes: adduser, adduser --system.
```

Comment: *off-topic* Geckos?

Comment: Some early Unix systems at Bell Labs used GECOS machines for print spooling and various other services, so this field was added to carry information on a user's GECOS identity (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field)

Comment: *off-topic*: can you make `adduser` idempotent? (if the user already exists, keep silent instead of prompting an error)

Comment: @Ragtime, that would only work for system accounts. It would be best to test if the user exists with something like `getent passwd <username>` before invoking `adduser`/`useradd`.

Answer (score 73):

[`useradd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/useradd.8.html) can also add users and does not appear to have any form of prompting built in.

```
useradd -m -p <encryptedPassword> -s /bin/bash <user>
```

- `-m`, `--create-home`: Create user home directory
- `-p`, `--password`: Specify user password; [skip to have it disabled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210228/add-a-user-wthout-password-but-with-ssh-and-public-key/210232#210232)
- `-s`, `--shell`: Default shell for logon user

  Blank will use default login shell specified by the `SHELL` variable in `/etc/default/useradd`
- Substitute `<user>` with the login name
- Substitute `<encryptedPassword>` with the **encrypted** password

---

### Generating a hashed password:

There are [a lot](https://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/generating-passwords-using-crypt3/) of crypt3 implementations that can generate a hashed password. The whole thing is your hashed password.

#### Sha-512 Based

The resulting output format: the hash mechanism (`$6` for sha-512), the random salt (the eight bytes after the second dollar sign `$ASDF1234`), remainder is the payload.

- mkpasswd `mkpasswd -m sha-512`

  (`mkpasswd` is provided by the `whois` package)

#### DES based:

The resulting output format:  first 2 bytes is your salt, remainder is the payload. The whole thing is your hashed password.

- mkpasswd: `mkpasswd` (provided by `whois` package)
- openssl: `openssl passwd -crypt`
- perl: `perl -e "print crypt('password');"`
- python: `python3 -c 'import crypt; print(crypt.crypt("password"))'`

Comment: The options you mention don’t exist for `adduser` on my (recent) version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @ᴠɪɴᴄᴇɴᴛ `adduser` is distinct from `useradd`, confusing I know.

Comment: Oops, indeed missed that you use its almost namesake … isn’t there a BDFL protecting the command line namespace? ;p

Comment: @mum007 This is only general advice, try adding `-v` or `-vv` or `-vvv` to your ssh commands to see whats wrong and search your error messages here on SO or Google.

Comment: Why encrypt the password? I've tried this with a normal password and it works. In my case, it's a temporary password that the user will need to change anyways.

Comment: I'm curios if @luca-ricci has an answer for you answerSeeker, they referenced the document https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-write-shell-script-to-add-user.html , I can see the advantage of never sending the cleartext password to the server, but I also don't think pre-encrypting the password is necessarily required.

Comment: @KovacsAkos try this: ```sudo sed -i"" -e "s/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config``` and ```sudo service ssh restart```

Comment: I suggest you START the answer by saying you're using a different command altogether. Newcomers will find it confusing otherwise. :)

Comment: To get the hashed password, you could also create the user interactively (e.g. in an ephemeral `ubuntu` docker container) and then extract the hashed value from `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: [On some versions of Ubuntu, `useradd` ignores user defaults](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321216/default-shell-not-being-selected-with-useradd), like the default shell.

Answer (score 24):

You can combine what @ThorSummoner @Zoke are saying like so:

```
username=jovyan
password=jovyan

adduser --gecos "" --disabled-password $username
chpasswd <<<"$username:$password"
```

I'm doing this for my Jupyter docker-stack. It allows full headless setup in a Dockerfile.

Comment: +1 for `chpasswd`. Much easier than fiddling with `mkpasswd` to make the hashes manually, and way more script-friendly.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: In case of issue with "<<<" (ex. Dockerfile), you could replace chpassword row by `echo "${username}:${password}" | chpasswd`