# Is there an automated way to batch create a set of users?

Tags: users, adduser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run adduser non-interactively](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94060/run-adduser-non-interactively)

I've looked into `adduser` and can see there are *some* modification flags that I can configure, but this still processes a single user at a time. Is there a way to process a whole batch of users at one time? I'm thinking of reading in an CSV with username and password.

It looks like FreeBSD's adduser had a hook for processing non-interactively.

Comment: The only thing it doesn't cover is adding a password. So maybe it's not really a duplicate after all.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet. Just. Use. Puppet. Instructions on install puppet are available [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146779/how-do-i-install-a-puppetmaster), and you can also use puppet without a puppetmaster.

```
user { "dave":

  ensure  => present,
  uid  => '507',
  gid  => 'admin',
  shell  => '/bin/zsh',
  home  => '/home/dave',
  managehome => true,
  password => 'password',
}
```

Put something like that in your puppet manifest, and you're good to go. More details on [page two of this PDF](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet_core_types_cheatsheet.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Step through the CSV in a loop, and run adduser once for each line.

Comment: OK, but how do I process the password automatically?

Comment: You'll have to do that with 2 commands. 1) adduser, and 2) passwd. You can send piped input to the passwd command, like this:

echo thePassword | passwd theUsername --stdin